# Neo4J multi-document transactions for standalone server

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am considering Neo4J for some project. I recall reading somewhere that multi-document ACID transactions are only supported for embedded database, but not for the standalone one. Searching at the Neo4J site, I could not find any info about this. Some more information about this, or some pointers could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j itself supports now transactions over the wire with 2.0

See: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html

Spring Data Neo4j does not yet and it will take a while until we get there, as it means to rewrite the core to use cypher throughout which it doesn't do now.

Comment: Good to know. On Spring-Data-Neo4j, any idea if it is in the roadmap, and if yes, any rough idea when it would come? Probably I can start using the embedded one, and migrate to REST when it becomes available? Thank you.

Comment: It is on the roadmap, no availability estimates, unfortunately, all a bandwidth issue. Yep the suggested migration is a good idea.